# Need to duplicate something manipulatable a large number of times with Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, duplicates, document.write

I need 1024 little widgets on screen to manipulate, and i wrote them out by aggressive copy pasting with classes of differing intervals... only to realize I couldn't get class names to work the way i needed.
So now i'm trying to make a script that writes 1024 duplicates to the page each with its own id and i'm completely unsure of myself with for loops.
Best i could think of was:

```
for(i=0; i < 1024; i++)
{document.write("<img src=\"token.png\" class=\"widget\" id=\"X"+i+"\">"}
```

any advice?

Comment: Dynamic ids almost always means "you're doing it wrong". Why do you need dynamic id values?

Comment: And... `document.write()` is also a good sign of problems to come. Use `var img = document.createElement("img"); img.src = ...; img.class = ...` and `elemnent.appendChild(img);`

Comment: Making a little math game using base 4, and because i need to manipulate a whole lot of them independently (like 4, 16, 64, or 256 at a time). With class names i ran into a wall with the function parameters that i could resolve if the items were id's rather than classes in a getElementsByClassName array.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your script to look like this:

```
var widgets = []
for(var i=0; i < 1024; i++){
    let item = document.createElement("span");
    item.classList.add("widget");
    widgets.push(item);
    document.body.appendChild(item);
}
```

And then add css looking like this.

```
.widget::after{
    content: url("token.png")
}
```

My reasoning:

- document.write is prone to xss, hard to read, and hard to write.
- If you need to be able to easily access your items later, array indexing will probably be faster than getElementById. If you're code will be passed items, without knowing their index, then having the index stored in the id would probably be more helpful.
- If every image will have the same file, then it's probably better to put it in css since it will save on load times. If there is a small set of images (say three different images), then create a class for each image. If the images change with each item, then revert to `<img>` and `src`.

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of ways, you could do to avoid the dynamic ids. You could group all of the widgets using a widget class and have another class that uniquely identifies the widget. Something like

```
<img class="widget widget-1" src="someUrl"/>
```

Or else, you could also have

```
 <img class="widget" src="someUrl"/>
```

and access them using the nth-child css selector, using *document.querySelector()*

Also, it is always recommended to avoid document.write method.Instead, you could use document.createElement / use a string literal representation and append the concatenated string once the loop is completed.

```
var container = document.CreateElement("div");

for (var idx = 0; idx < 1024; idx++) {
  var imageElement = document.createElement("img");
  imageElement.classList.add("widget");
  // In the above case , you need to use document.querySelector("img:nth-child(someIdx)")
  //or 
  imageElement.classList.add("widget", "widget" + idx);
  // In the above case , you need to use document.querySelector("img.widget-"+someIdx)")
  container.append(imageElement);
}

document.querySelector("body").append(container);
```